# Fetching referrer URL from a Github-Issue embedded image

Tags: github, markdown

We want to place an embedded image to a Github issue eg.

https://github.com/org/repo/issues/101

`![a cool badge](http://ourserver.io/badge/)`

[image: sample badge]

On /badge endpoint, our server wants to render a SVG file specific to that issue with special information attached to it (accepted/rejected/stale/etc), but request object doesn't seem to contain the referrer URL, in this case `https://github.com/org/repo/issues/101`
 (using node/express), thus we can't distinguish one badge from another on the server side without including additional information on the query string.

Is there a way for us to catch the referring URL before creating the badge?

PS: I am aware of [this](https://help.github.com/articles/about-anonymized-image-urls/) limitation, though, since we are not interested in user-browser-specific data, just the URL of the issue that badge needs to be rendered to, thought I'd just ask.

PPS: Our current solution is to generate embed code per issue on our landing page, we'd like to eliminate that step and have a universal embed code that's valid on every issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All GitHub images are proxied by https://github.com/atmos/camo for security reasons (typically, to avoid mixed-content warnings when users paste HTTP URLs in HTTPS-only GitHub).

GitHub purposefully makes sure that the image's location (eg. the GitHub issue's URL) does not leak to the image's origin server (eg. ourserver.io). See the following discussion on the subject: https://github.com/atmos/camo/issues/43.

The solution is to put the information in the image's URL: `http://ourserver.io/badge/github/org/repo/issues/101`.

Comment: thanks for the answer. though, i don't see why would referrer url should not be sent with the headers or considered a leak. that could open up plenty of possibilities for third party development and i don't see any downside to it. maybe i'm wrong. for now, we are implementing it the way you are suggested and keep it that way.